# Open and read a .RAW file

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I need to writing a MATLAB program that will read this image file [Download here.](http://www.speedyshare.com/CKGdg/e6712s4i50.raw)

This picture shows the instruction and the expected result I have tried the following code, but I couldn't get the expected results.
[image]

```
row=256;   col=256;
f=fopen('e6712s4i50.raw','r');
a=fread(f, [col row],'*int16');
Z=a;
imshow(Z)
```

How do I read this picture correctly?

Comment: use `imread` for images

Comment: @Adriaan I tried but it gives me an error.

Comment: Then please be so kind as to share the error message with us.

Comment: @Adriaan: imread does not support raw

Comment: @fara: You are reading the file from the beginning, you have to skip the header using `fseek`

Comment: a .`raw` file format is undefined. `.raw` means literally that, raw. Its raw, unmodified data, its whatever the sensor has spit out. Therefore, there is no way of stadarizing `.raw` fileformat reading. No one can help you unless we know exactly how the file is written

Comment: Actually I just read the **NOTE** you posted. That note is tellign you how to read the `.raw` file. Do exactly what it says, and if you have troubles trying to do that, then we will help. But we are not going to code it from scratch for you!

Comment: @Adriaan : This is an error : Error using fopen
Invalid filename.

Error in imread (line 343)
    fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

Comment: @fara Do not use imread. Follow my comments.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Thank you for your help. I'm beginner in Matlab and I'm trying to read this picture.

Comment: @fara Yes, I know that. Please, follow my advice. I suggest you close this question, try to solve it yourself by following the **note** in the image you posted , and if you have problems opena new question with the new code

Comment: @Daniel  Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Thank you. I was able to solve it.

Comment: @fara Then I encourage you to write the answer in here! ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check below code:

```
fid = fopen('raw.raw')
rawdata = fread(fid, inf, '*uint8')
fclose(fid);
B = reshape(rawdata(2:2:131072),256,256)';
Y = circshift(B,[240 140]);
imshow(Y)
```

whats about this?

Comment: But, the OPs file has a header. 8432 bytes long specifically.

Comment: @user5719313, Thank you much it's pretty close, just the bottom of picture is not clear. seems like have some noise on the bottom of image. by any chance do you know why?